# How use template function for a templated functor

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I need to sort std::pair, the second element are different struct, ideally i would like to have a single elegant function but i could also do overloaded function, unfortunately even with overloaded functions its not compiling because of : `<unresolved overloaded function type>`

```
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
} myStruct;

template <typename S> static bool comp(std::pair<int, S> pair1, std::pair<int, S> pair2){
    
    auto val1 = std::get<int>(pair1);
    auto val2 = std::get<int>(pair2);
    
    return val1 < val2;
}


int main(){
    
    myStruct test;
    
    std::vector<std::pair<int, myStruct>> v {{9,test}, {2,test}, {4,test}, {3,test}, {1,test}};
    
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp); 

}
```

Comment: `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp<myStruct>)`?

Comment: Anyway, the verbatim error messages would tell us what's wrong, but your question is missing that. Please edit your question to contain the full, exact error message

Comment: question have been answer 3 time so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is OK, but there are only one problems with this code.

1. The sort function MUST know the type of the functor since it cannot be deduced, so you should write:

```cpp
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp<myStruct>);
```

in order to let your compiler know what function to "instantiate" within the Two-phase name lookup

Comment: for the second part you are right, but for the first one its in the c++ doc and its working fine

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/get

Comment: Yes! You are right. From C++14 onwards, ```std::get``` allows type-based access. I just edited that.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

`comp` is a name of a template. `comp` is not a function, whose name evaluates to a function pointer. `comp` is a template. The third parameter to `std::sort` is not a template name. It's a callable object, of some kind. There are certain requirements for that callable object, but that's immaterial here.

How do you make a callable object out of a template? Instantiate this template. How do you instantiate a template? You specify what it's parameters are.

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp<myStruct>);
```

In many instances template parameters can be deduced, but not in this case, for rather complicated reasons.